# Dealing with large sum of distinct values in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

Newbie to python, to the world of data analytics with python.
I am working on practice data where one of the columns has 87 distinct values and other column has 888 distinct values where I am thinking to delete the latter column. I just don't understand how do I deal with these columns. Do I group these columns or delete the columns. If I group, then how do I go about it!?  Really appreciate your ideas. @Toby Petty @Vaishali

Ex:

`import pandas as pd
 import bumpy as np`

`print("Count of distinct entries for car:", len(set(car_sales['car'])))

 print("Distinct entries for car:", set(car_sales['car']))`

`Count of distinct entries for car: 87
Distinct entries for car: {'Lamborghini', 'ËUAZ', 'Daewoo', 'Jeep', 'Ferrari', 'Bentley', 'Mercury', 'MINI', 'Acura', 'Land Rover', 'Aston Martin', 'Fisker', 'Dodge', 'Fiat', 'MG', 'Samsung', 'Rolls-Royce', 'SsangYong', 'Hyundai', 'Lincoln', 'Ford', 'Moskvich-Izh', 'Samand', 'Audi', 'Dadi', 'Geely', 'Dacia', 'Daihatsu', 'Maserati', 'Volkswagen', 'Peugeot', 'Volvo', 'Nissan', 'SMA', 'Hummer', 'Porsche', 'Subaru', 'Alfa Romeo', 'Saab', 'Buick', 'Mazda', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'Lexus', 'Hafei', 'Renault', 'Suzuki', 'Chrysler', 'BYD', 'Moskvich-AZLK', 'Jaguar', 'Smart', 'ZAZ', 'Groz', 'Infiniti', 'TATA', 'Lifan', 'ZX', 'Isuzu', 'Rover', 'Honda', 'Mitsubishi', 'Cadillac', 'FAW', 'Aro', 'Wartburg', 'GMC', 'Great Wall', 'Lancia', 'Bogdan', 'Kia', 'BMW', 'JAC', 'Tesla', 'Seat', 'Barkas', 'VAZ', 'Huanghai', 'Toyota', 'Citroen', 'Other-Retro', 'Chery', 'Opel', 'Chevrolet', 'Skoda', 'UAZ', 'Changan', 'GAZ'}`

Comment: Check pandas.DataFrame.groupby + pandas.DataFrame.sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is your question?

**Update**: After some clarification/guessing, I am going to assume that the question is about two issues:

1. How to limit a `groupby` to only the top `k` groups (by some aggregate of choice).
2. How to summarize columns, including some non-numeric ones.

For starters, `sns` contains some beautiful datasets that are very handy for such questions, for example, below we will use 'mpg', which contains some car and mileage information.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
```

We are going to split the supplied `name` into a `brand` and `model`:

```
df[['brand', 'model']] = pd.DataFrame(df.name.str.split(' ', n=1).values.tolist())
df.head(3)

Out[]:
    mpg  cylinders  displacement  horsepower  weight  acceleration  \
0  18.0          8         307.0       130.0    3504          12.0   
1  15.0          8         350.0       165.0    3693          11.5   
2  18.0          8         318.0       150.0    3436          11.0   

   model_year origin                       name      brand            model  
0          70    usa  chevrolet chevelle malibu  chevrolet  chevelle malibu  
1          70    usa          buick skylark 320      buick      skylark 320  
2          70    usa         plymouth satellite   plymouth        satellite
```

For later, we'll add a column `n` which we'll use to count how many entries we have for our stats:

```
df['n'] = 1
```

Look for top 5 groups, according to maximum `acceleration` (the OP wants to use total sales, so in his case we would use `sales.sum()` instead of `acceleration.max()`, but here we don't have sales figures). The main point is to build an index of the groups we want to report on (and rename the others as 'Others'). We turn that index, that we call `idx`, into a list of tuples for easier subsetting.

```
idx = df.groupby(['brand', 'model']).acceleration.max().sort_values(ascending=False).head(5).index.to_list()
idx

Out[]:
[('peugeot', '504'),
 ('vw', 'pickup'),
 ('vw', 'dasher (diesel)'),
 ('volkswagen', 'type 3'),
 ('chevrolet', 'chevette')]
```

Now build a boolean selector `top10`, which is `True` for the selected groups.

```
top10 = df.set_index(['brand', 'model']).index.isin(idx)
```

Rename the others:

```
df.loc[~top10, 'brand'] = 'Other'
df.loc[~top10, 'model'] = ''
```

Now, for columns that are not numeric, we choose to report the majority value (the most frequent within the group).

```
from collections import Counter
def majority(*args):
    return Counter(*args).most_common(1)[0][0]

# example
majority('z a b a a c d'.split())

Out[]:
'a'
```

Finally, we define a dict of aggregators to be used for the various columns:

```
# numeric: use mean
desired = {k:'mean' for k in df.columns if np.issubdtype(df[k], np.number)}
# simplified:
desired = {k:'mean' for k in ['mpg', 'horsepower', 'weight']}

# non-numeric: use majority    
desired.update({'origin': majority})

# also report the size of each group
desired.update({'n': 'sum'})
```

Now, do the groupby and aggregate:

```
df.groupby(['brand', 'model']).agg(desired)

Out[]:
                                  mpg  horsepower       weight  origin    n
brand      model                                                           
Other                       23.340052  105.540682  2984.651163     usa  387
chevrolet  chevette         30.400000   63.250000  2090.250000     usa    4
peugeot    504              23.550000   83.500000  3022.250000  europe    4
volkswagen type 3           23.000000   54.000000  2254.000000  europe    1
vw         dasher (diesel)  43.400000   48.000000  2335.000000  europe    1
           pickup           44.000000   52.000000  2130.000000  europe    1
```

Comment: `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cars = [['Ford',15500.0,'crossover',68,2.5,'Gas','yes',2010,'Kuga','full'],
        ['Mercedes-Benz',20500.0,'sedan',173,1.8,'Gas','yes',2011,'E-Class','rear'],
        ['Mercedes-Benz',20500.0,"Other",173,1.8,'Gas','yes',2011,'E-Class','rear'],
        ['Ford',15500.0,"Other",68,2.5,'Gas','yes',2010,'Kuga','full']] 

car_sales = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns=['car','price','body','mileage','engV','engType','registration','year','model','drive'])`

Comment: This is my dataframe I want to create a new column as car1 beside car which will have Volkswagen, Mercedes-Benz, BMW, Toyota, VAZ, Renault, Audi, Opel, Skoda, Nissan and 77 remaining values as others

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Could you please update the question with a minimal example of input and desired output?  A minimal example is one that describes the spirit of your question with a very abridged set up, i.e. just a few lines of code. In your case, that may be perhaps 2 columns and 4 or 5 rows on the input.

Comment: I ve a column in my data having 87 distinct values(car brands), against each of the car brands, sales and other attributes are given in another column. So want to sort top 10 car brands and remaining 77 values I want club under 'Others' so that while making charts I can show these top 10 car brands(and remaining clubbed in 'Others' ) in my analysis.Data frame is as follows:

 `cars = [['Ford',15500.0,'crossover',68,2.5], ['Mercedes',20500.0,'sedan',173,1.8], ['Mercedes',26500.0,'crossover',173,2.8]]`

`car_sales = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns=['car','price','body','mileage','engV'])`

Comment: You still haven't described your problem properly. What do you mean by 'top 10 car brands'? "Top 10" implies an ordering. What is that ordering? by total sales, by total mileage, or by number of models, by low consumption, by something else? How do you want to group cars? Just by brand, or by brand and body, or what?  When grouping, you could compute various statistics for the numeric values (e.g. "mean", "min", "max", "median"). How do you want to treat the non-numerical columns?

Comment: Hi, I was trying to order it by total sales. Anyways the problem is solved.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well, not so fast. We must leave this Q and A in a better shape. Otherwise, other people will be confused and definitely not get any help from this.

Comment: Yes. This works fine. Limiting groupby was the issue and now it is solved. Thank you very much for being so helpful.